# How to install Polymerfire with all dependencies?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

[I am trying to install and use the Polymerfire `<firebase-auth>` element](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire). But, apparently, I have not successfully installed all the dependencies like firebase-sdk, for example.

I tried using Bower command pattern used to install the other Polymer elements:

command line

```
bower install --save polymerfire/firebase-auth
```

but, apparently, [Polymerfire might not be setup for Bower](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/27) and I received the following error.

> fatal: remote error:
>     Repository not found.

As it stands now, [I have the following dependencies listed in the Polymerfire bower.json file](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/blob/master/bower.json):

bower.json

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.2.0",
  "firebase-sdk": "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.0/firebase.js",
  "app-storage": "polymerelements/app-storage#~0.9.0"
},
...
```

But I do not, I repeat, I do not, have any firebase-sdk directory in my project's bower_components directory.

Please help me unravel this and correctly install all the necessary dependencies for Polymerfire (including firebase-sdk) into my Polymer project.

### Edit

When I do the following command:

command line

```
bower install --save polymerfire
```

It *appears* to work. However, when I check my bower_components directory, I still do not see any firebase-sdk subdirectory and I still get the same console error. [Click here to see another question dealing with this error in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37671257/1640892).

console.log

> firebase-app.html:94
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Comment: Given that the answer for both questions is exactly the same, why shouldn't they be marked as duplicates?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Personally, I never thought the conclusion *two questions with the same answer must, therefore, be the same question* was logically correct. For example: What is 7 + 2? What is 3-squared? If I buy a dozen eggs and eat three, how many eggs would I have left? And which digit most closely resembles 6 turned upside down? Same answer. Different questions. In this case, I had to ask the second question to narrow the focus after I got a lead on the answer to the first. That said, I leave the answer to *your* question of possible duplication to the judgment of your wisdom, sir.

Comment: *sigh* You are right that many different questions can have the same answer, but this is not one of them. Closing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
bower install --save firebase/polymerfire
```

Note: `bower install --save polymerfire` points to DivShot's version which is now outdated.